# Where to store data in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch

I have following case to handle:

My mobile application ( Sencha Touch App wrapped in native container ) has around 5000 book titles. Now, I don't want application to ping server to get these books on his mobile. Application will need to access this data during run time. So should I

a) dump the data into sqlite at the time of installation of the application ? (First time run)
b) Fetch data from files only. ( I will be making sorting and querying operations over this data - may not be a good solution if I store the entire file in an array at once and process it further )

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 1):

Create a JSON API to fetch your data from a database on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can store this data in JSON file and then use JSON proxy to load/sort/query it.
BUT its better to expose a web service, just like what Diodeus said.